# Making a Point check for adjacent matches and then having those adjacent matches check for matches and add all to a HashSet

Tags: java

I'm trying to add adjacent matches to a point to a HashSet, and the check those adjacent points for adjacent equal points and add them to the same HashSet. I'm having trouble adding the adjacent points and checking them for adjacent points. It's similar to how bejeweled matches are made.

```
public class matchFinder {

    private HashSet<Point> adjacentAndMatching(Point p, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> board) {
        HashSet<Point> result = new HashSet<Point>();
        if (p != null) {
            Point check;
            check = new Point(p.x-1,p.y); if (inBounds(check, board) && matches(p,check,board)) { result.add(check); }
            check = new Point(p.x+1,p.y); if (inBounds(check, board) && matches(p,check,board)) { result.add(check); }
            check = new Point(p.x,p.y-1); if (inBounds(check, board) && matches(p,check,board)) { result.add(check); }
            check = new Point(p.x,p.y+1); if (inBounds(check, board) && matches(p,check,board)) { result.add(check); }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean matches(Point p, Point q, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _board) {
        return _board.get(p.x).get(p.y).equals(_board.get(q.x).get(q.y));
    }

    private boolean inBounds(Point p, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _board) {
        return p.x >=0 && p.x < _board.size() && p.y >= 0 && p.y < _board.get(0).size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the hashcode method in your `Point` class? You need to do that for custom classes to specify how hashing is done when adding elements to a hashset.